# RECEIVING email from Django website

Tags: python, django, email, yahoo

I would like to enable people that visit my website to be able to send me an email to my yahoo mail. How can I do this? Now, I don't have a mail server (yet). Would it be necessary? The idea is for the person sending the email to fill in his email, subject and message, and then it would be posted to my yahoo email.

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form  = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = request.POST.get['subject']
            email = request.POST.get['email']
            message = request.POST.get['message']
            if subject and email and message:
                try:
                    send_mail(subject, message, email, ['my_email@yahoo.com'], fail_silently=False,)
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                return redirect('thanks')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Make sure to have all fields filled.')
    return render(request,"mywebsit/contact.html", {'form':form})
```

The form renders ok, but when I press send it acts as if it has sent the message, but when I open my yahoo mail there's nothing new there.

I read it would be necessary to configure some things at `settings.py`, but, as far as I get it, it is meant to SEND, whereas what I want is to RECEIVE.

Inspite of that, I tried configuring it,

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yahoopassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'email@yahoo.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'email@yahoo.com'
```

and then what I get is this error:

> smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a networking issue, Are you hosting your website? Also the mail server depends on how much traffic your site is getting, if there is a lot then yeah it's a good idea but if not just having an HTML code that hyperlinks a new window to compose an email to your Yahoo account can do the trick too.

Comment: it's not hosted yet. I'm still doing it through the Django development server tool. But hey, good idea about the new window thing.

Comment: Oh alright, looks like you just had a bad port then, but anytime. If you still want to try the new window HTML code there's a great website called JavaScript Kit. Google it they have some great free templates for your website that you can build off of. Good luck on your website! -Duncan

Answer (score 0):

It should be request.post.get('Subject')

You are using [] bracket but it should be ()  bracket